# How can I align the numbers of the table by decimals with dcolumn package?

Tags: tables, dcolumn

I'm looking for a way to align the numbers of the table by decimals. Any thoughts of what could be wrong?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel} 
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{\cdot}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l*{1}{ccccc}}
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{Cuadro I}\\
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{Estadísticas descriptivas GEIH} \\
    \hline\hline
    &\multicolumn{5}{c}{}                                            \\
    &           Obs&        Media&          Desviación Estándar&         Min&         Máx\\
    \hline
    Ocupados    &   96703         &  .896&    .306&           0&           1\\
    Años de educación         &  96703          &    10.583&    4.331&           0&          26\\
    Soltero     &  96703          &    .281&     .449&           0&           1\\
    Jefe de hogar  &  96703          &    .435&    .496&           0&           1\\
    Edad       &    96703        &    39.301&    13.824&          18&         100\\
    \hline
    Ocupados según nivel de estudio       &      &            &            &            &            \\
    Ninguno     & 586599            &    .546&    .498&           0&           1\\
    Bachiller   &  586599          &    .203&    .402&           0&           1\\
    Técnico    &  586599          &    .161&    .367&           0&           1\\
    Universitario& 586599           &    .065&    .246&           0&           1\\
    Postgrado   &  586599          &    .000&    .007&           0&           1\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include the d column type, now is there.

Comment: it's always easier for people to see the issue and test answers if you priovide a complete test document not a fragment as above which needs to be edited to make run

Comment: Actually I get a text error for  `\begin{tabular}{l*{1}{ccccc}}{d{3.2}}\multicolumn{5 the d{3.2}`

Comment: the error is because that is typesetting `d3.2` in the first cell, so `\multicolumn` comes too late, you intended the `d` column to be inside the first argument, bot after it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You declared the `d` type but did not use it, something like

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

% use utf-8 \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{\cdot}{#1}}
\begin{document}
% l*{1}{ccccc} is the same as lccccc and doesn't use d!

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l d{6.0} d{2.3} d{2.3} d{2.0} d{3.0} @{}}
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{Cuadro I}\\
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{Estadísticas descriptivas GEIH} \\
    \hline\hline
\\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Obs}& 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Media}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Desviación\\Estándar\end{tabular}}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Min}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Máx}\\
    \hline
    Ocupados    &   96703         &  .896&    .306&           0&           1\\
    Años de educación         &  96703          &    10.583&    4.331&           0&          26\\
    Soltero     &  96703          &    .281&     .449&           0&           1\\
    Jefe de hogar  &  96703          &    .435&    .496&           0&           1\\
    Edad       &    96703        &    39.301&    13.824&          18&         100\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{@{}c@{}}{Ocupados según nivel de estudio}\\
    Ninguno     & 586599            &    .546&    .498&           0&           1\\
    Bachiller   &  586599          &    .203&    .402&           0&           1\\
    Técnico    &  586599          &    .161&    .367&           0&           1\\
    Universitario& 586599           &    .065&    .246&           0&           1\\
    Postgrado   &  586599          &    .000&    .007&           0&           1\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

but the horizontal rules would look better if you used `\midrule` from the  `booktabs` package.

Comment: a prefix  `\cdot` with no preceding 0 looks a lot like a `-` are you sure you want this format?

Comment: How can I change the prefix  `\cdot` to look like decimal, instead of `-` ? @DavidCarlisle

Comment: @FelipeTorresCruz use `.` (or perhaps `,` since this is Spanish?)  instead of `\cdot`

Comment: Is spanish. Its weird when I use `\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}` I get a text error but when i use `\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{,}{#1}}` it works. However I need `.` instead of the  `,` . Any ideas of what could be the problem? Or how it could be solved?   @DavidCarlisle

Comment: +1. :-) I would replace `\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{Ocupados según nivel de estudio}` with `\multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{Ocupados según nivel de estudio}`, though.

Comment: I tried `\multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{Ocupados según nivel de estudio}` but its the same result @Mico

Comment: @Mico I did do that I swear:-) Let me re-post....

Comment: @FelipeTorresCruz see update

Comment: I keep getting the same result @DavidCarlisle

Comment: same result as what? @FelipeTorresCruz

Comment: I get `.` as `-` @DavidCarlisle

Comment: @FelipeTorresCruz - Are you *sure* that `\multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{Ocupados según nivel de estudio} but its the same result as `Ocupados según nivel de estudio`?

Comment: @FelipeTorresCruz that is not possible. If you use `\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}` then you get [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRGr3.png)

Comment: Is there any package that maybe you are using, that Im not? Are you using the update of the code that you posted? Could you please show me the code that you are using? @DavidCarlisle

Comment: @FelipeTorresCruz exactly the document in this answer, but changing the newcolumntype line as shown

Comment: It finally work!!! But I had to use `\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{,}{.}{#1}}` and change `.` for  `,` for each number in the table. @DavidCarlisle

Comment: Thank you for all your help @DavidCarlisle

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I would present the table, with `siunitx`. This has several advantages, for instance automatic uniformization of the decimal separator and automatic formatting of large numbers.

Also numbers should *always* show the integer part and `siunitx` adds it automatically, if it is absent.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption{Estadísticas descriptivas GEIH}\label{add-here-a-label}

\medskip

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  S[table-format=6.0]
  S[table-format=2.3]
  S[table-format=2.3]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=3.0]
  @{}
}
\toprule
& {Obs} & {Media} & {DE} & {Min} & {Máx} \\
\midrule
Ocupados          &  96703 &   .896 &   .306 &  0 &   1 \\
Años de educación &  96703 & 10.583 &  4.331 &  0 &  26 \\
Soltero           &  96703 &   .281 &   .449 &  0 &   1 \\
Jefe de hogar     &  96703 &   .435 &   .496 &  0 &   1 \\
Edad              &  96703 & 39.301 & 13.824 & 18 & 100 \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{@{}l@{}}{\itshape Ocupados según nivel de estudio} \\
Ninguno           & 586599 &   .546 &   .498 &  0 &   1 \\
Bachiller         & 586599 &   .203 &   .402 &  0 &   1 \\
Técnico           & 586599 &   .161 &   .367 &  0 &   1 \\
Universitario     & 586599 &   .065 &   .246 &  0 &   1 \\
Postgrado         & 586599 &   .000 &   .007 &  0 &   1 \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{6}{@{}l@{}}{\footnotesize DE: Desviación Estándar} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to change  `,`  for `.` ? @egreg

Comment: @FelipeTorresCruz Remove the `\sisetup` line.

Comment: I tried to use `\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}` but i get the following error "File `l3backend-pdfmode.def' not found." @egreg

Comment: Thank you for your help @egreg

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions and comments, in no particular order:

- You define the `d` column type but then don't seem to use it in the header of the `tabular` environment. I suggest that you replace

  ```
  \begin{tabular}{l*{1}{ccccc}}
  ```

  with

  ```
  \begin{tabular}{@{} l d{6.0} d{2.3} d{2.3} d{2.0} d{3.0} @{}}
  ```
- Since the contents of the five header cells are not numeric, you need to smuggle them past `dcolumn`. See the use of `\mc` in the example below.
- If you want to use commas as decimal separators in the pdf file, you should also change `\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{\cdot}{#1}}` to `\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{,}{#1}}`.
- Use a `table` environment, and use the machinery of the `caption` package to customize the appearance of the captions. That way, you can cross-reference the table elsewhere in the document via LaTeX's `\label`-`\ref` system.
- Replace

  ```
  \usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
  ```

  with

  ```
  \usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
  ```
- Replace

  ```
  Ocupados según nivel de estudio & & & & & \\
  ```

  with

  ```
  \multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{Ocupados según nivel de estudio} \\
  ```

  to give the table a much more compact appearance. Relatedly, do split `Desviación Estándar` across 2 lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel} 
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
%%%\usepackage{amsfonts} % is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'
\usepackage{psfrag}  % are you sure you need this package?
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[2]{D{.}{,}{#1}}

%% new material:
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[labelsep=newline,skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\renewcommand\thetable{\Roman{table}}
\newcommand\mc[2]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[spanish,nameinlink]{cleveref} % optional

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\caption{Estadísticas descriptivas GEIH} \label{tab:GEIH}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l d{6.0} d{2.3} d{2.3} d{2.0} d{3.0} @{}}
\toprule
    & \mc{Obs}& \mc{Media} & \mc{Desviación}& \mc{Min} & \mc{Máx}\\
    &&& \mc{Estándar}\\
\midrule
    Ocupados          &  96703 &  0.896 &  0.306 &  0 &   1\\
    Años de educación &  96703 & 10.583 &  4.331 &  0 &  26\\
    Soltero           &  96703 &  0.281 &  0.449 &  0 &   1\\
    Jefe de hogar     &  96703 &  0.435 &  0.496 &  0 &   1\\
    Edad              &  96703 & 39.301 & 13.824 & 18 & 100\\
\midrule
    \multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{Ocupados según nivel de estudio} \\
    Ninguno           & 586599 &  0.546 &  0.498 &  0 &   1\\
    Bachiller         & 586599 &  0.203 &  0.402 &  0 &   1\\
    Técnico           & 586599 &  0.161 &  0.367 &  0 &   1\\
    Universitario     & 586599 &  0.065 &  0.246 &  0 &   1\\
    Postgrado         & 586599 &  0.000 &  0.007 &  0 &   1\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

Una referencia cruzada al \cref{tab:GEIH}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Mik text doesnt recognize some of the packages, so I get an error @Mico

Comment: @FelipeTorresCruz all those packages are in an up to date miktex, you may need to update using miktex package manager (in user and admin modes if you hav eboth)

Comment: Thank you for all your help @Mico

Comment: @FelipeTorresCruz - *Which* packages aren't recognized?